# Using absolute/fixed positioning in CSS grid

Tags: html, css

I am trying use absolute positioning in one of my divs that has display: grid styled for it. Basically an image which is the grandchild of a div, I need it to have position: absolute for it specifically. I understand that you can achieve this however, I added a border to the grandparent div to see whether or not it was working correctly and it seems that the image bleeds out of the border yet still is positioned correctly according to the grid I set up.

Here is the CSS:

```
.one {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, minmax(auto, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 5vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.description {
    grid-column: 2/4;
}

.image {
    grid-column: 5/-1;
    position: relative;
}

.image img {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.image img.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="one">
            <div class="details">
                <span class="s-highlight">An Inquiry on Food Waste</span><br><br> Publication
                <br><br> 2018
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                    <img class="visible" id="satu" src="assets/img/1/1-5.png" alt="">
                    <img id="satu" src="assets/img/1/1-2.png" alt="">
                    <img id="satu" src="assets/img/1/1-6.png" alt="">
                    <img id="satu" src="assets/img/1/1-7.png" alt="">
                    <img id="satu" src="assets/img/1/1-8.png" alt="">
                    <img id="satu" src="assets/img/1/1-10.png" alt="">
                    <img id="satu" src="assets/img/1/1-9.png" alt="">

            </div>
        </div>
```

The border only extends to the text but not to the image which is bigger thus having the image bleed over the border. What might be causing the border to not extend to the rest of the image?

Comment: You haven't told the `img` how big to be...you need to specify height & width as 100%

Comment: A small demo would be useful.